# Do modern CPU's have compression instructions

Tags: cpu-architecture, instructions

I have been curious about this for awhile since compression is used in about everything.

- Are there any basic compression support instructions in the silicon on a typical modern CPU chip?
- If not, why are they not included?
- Why is this different from encryption, where some CPUs have hardware support for algorithms such as AES?

Comment: AES does encryption, not compression: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard

Comment: Are you asking about compression/decompression or encryption/decryption?

Comment: @Stephen C What I was referring to is, AES has processor instructions, why not compression instructions to make LZ4 faster (or any other "standard" data compression algorithm)

Comment: I have edited your question to correct the ambiguity.

Comment: Which of the 100's of lossless and or lossy compressions should be supported?

Answer (score 9):

They don’t have **general-purpose compression** instructions.

AES operates on very small data blocks, it accepts two 128 bit inputs, does some non-trivial computations on them, produces single 128 bit output. A dedicated instruction to speed up computation helps a lot.

On modern hardware, lossless compression speed is often limited by RAM latency. Dedicated instruction can’t improve speed, bigger and faster caches can, but modern CPUs already have very sophisticated multi-level caches. They work good enough for compression already.

If you need to compress many gigabits/second, there’re [several](http://www.aha.com/data-compression/) [standalone](https://www.cavium.com/news/cavium-networks-introduces-octeon-plus-based-accelerators-for-appliance-blade-server-and-storage-systems) [accelerators](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Archive/2016/33/Boosting-Performance-with-Intel-s-QuickAssist-Technology), but these are not parts of processors, usually standalone chips connected to PCIx. And they are very niche products because most users just don't need to compress that much data that fast.

However, modern CPUs have a lot of stuff for lossy **multimedia compression**.
Most of them have multiple vector instruction set extensions (mmx, sse, avx), and some of these instructions help a lot for e.g. video compression use case. For example, `_mm_sad_pu8` (SSE), `_mm_sad_epu8` (SSE2), `_mm256_sad_epu8` (AVX2) are very helpful for estimating compression errors of 8x8 blocks of 8 bit pixels. The AVX2 version processes 4 rows of the block in just a few cycles (5 cycles on Haswell, 1 on Skylake, 2 on Ryzen).

Finally, many CPUs have integrated GPUs which include specialized silicon for hardware video encoding and decoding, usually h.264, newer ones also h.265. Here's a table for [Intel GPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HD,_UHD_and_Iris_Graphics#Capabilities_(GPU_video_acceleration)), AMD has separate names for [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Coding_Engine) and [decoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Video_Decoder) parts. That silicon is even more power efficient than SIMD instructions in the cores.

Comment: Compression accelerators are included in some processor chips (e.g., Cavium's [OCTEON](https://www.cavium.com/news/cavium-networks-introduces-octeon-plus-based-accelerators-for-appliance-blade-server-and-storage-systems)). Intel's QuickAssist Technology includes compression accelerators. Energy efficiency is one motive for such accelerators.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton Not included, they are standalone chips. But I’ve updated my answer adding your links.

Comment: "Compression speed often limited by RAM latency. Dedicated instruction can’t improve speed, bigger and faster caches can, but modern CPUs already have very sophisticated multi-level caches. They work good enough for compression already." Are you saying that all researchers who have studied implementing compression algorithms in hardware for many years are insane?

Comment: "They don’t." Is that for compression or AES or both? x86 does include instructions for AES.

Comment: @HadiBrais "Are you saying that all researchers who have studied implementing compression algorithms in hardware for many years are insane?" No, I'm not.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton and Soonts: Intel QuickSync is [on-chip hardware video compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video#Hardware_decoding_and_encoding), into h.264 / h.265 / JPEG / VP8/9 / VC-1.  It's a bit of a special case, though, because it's built-in to the GPU which just happens to be on-die, not the IA cores.  And it's only lossy video compression.  (Unless it has a lossless mode for any of the formats?  Probably not).

Comment: @PeterCordes Right, I know about QuickSync. But because the OP written “compression is used in about everything”, I concluded that they are not interested in the multimedia special case.
For multimedia compression CPUs offer a lot, albeit not directly. That was a selling point for various vector extension, e.g. long ago mmx meant “MultiMedia eXtension”.

Comment: I thought it was at least worth mentioning that there *is* fixed-function compression hardware in modern x86 CPUs.  But yeah, good point that audio/video (de)compression is still one of the major use-cases for SIMD inside the CPU cores.  [`psadbw`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PSADBW.html) is obviously designed for doing two 8x8 motion-searches in parallel (in the SSE2 XMM version), in video compression.  (And has other uses, of course, like horizontal sum of bytes).  SSE4.1 even added `mpsadbw`, but it's not fast enough to be worth using for exhaustive motion search.

Comment: Intel's new [Sapphire Rapids chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapphire_Rapids) will include an integrated compression accelerator (although it's still accessed over PCI, it's not an ISA extension)

Answer (score 4):

Many applications in all kinds of domains certainly can benefit from and do use data compression algorithms. So it would be nice to have hardware support for compression and/or decompression, similar to having hardware support for other popular functions such as encryption/decryption, various mathematical transformations, bit counting, and others. However, compression/decompression typically operate on large amounts of data (many MBs or more) and different algorithms exhibit different memory access patterns that are potentially either not friendly to traditional memory hierarchies or even adversely impacted by them. In addition, as a result of operating on large amounts of data and if implemented directly in the main CPU pipeline, the CPU would almost be fully busy for long periods of time doing compression or decompression. On the other hand, consider encryption for example, encrypting small amounts of data is typical, and so it would make sense to have hardware support for encryption directly in the CPU.

It is precisely for these reasons why hardware compression/decompression engines (accelerators) have been implemented either as ASICs or on FPGAs by many companies as coprocessors (on-die, on-package, or external) or expansion cards (connected through PCIe/NVMe) including:

- [Intel QuickAssist adapters](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ethernet-products/gigabit-server-adapters/quickassist-adapter-for-servers.html).
- [Microsoft Xpress](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/compression-accelerators/).
- [IBM PCIe data compression/decompression card](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/linuxonibm/liabt/liabtpcie3fpga.htm).
- [Cisco hardware compression adapters](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/wan/data-compression/14156-compress-overview.html).
- [AHA378](http://www.aha.com/DrawProducts.aspx?Action=GetProductDetails&ProductID=41).
- Many academic [porposals](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7160039/).

That said, it is possible to achieve very high throughputs on a single modern x86 core. Intel published a [paper](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-deflate-decompression-paper.pdf) in 2010 in which it discusses the results of an implementation, called `igunzip`, of the DEFLATE decompression algorithm. They used a single  Nehalem-based physical core and experimented with using a single logical core and two logical cores. They achieve impressive decompression throughputs of more than 2 Gbits/s. The key x86 instruction is [PCLMULQDQ](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PCLMULQDQ.html). However, modern hardware accelerators (such as QuickAssist) can perform about 10 times faster.

Intel has a number of related patents:

- [Apparatus for Hardware Implementation of Lossless Data Compression](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20160283504A1/en).
- [Hardware apparatuses and methods for data decompression](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20170187388A1/en).
- [Systems, Methods, and Apparatuses for Decompression using Hardware and Software](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20170093424A1/en).
- [Systems, methods, and apparatuses for compression using hardware and software](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9473168B1/en).

Although it's hard to determine which Intel products employed the techniques or designs proposed in these patents.

Comment: Password hashing isn't a great example, I don't think; it's too much of a one-off.  En/Decrypting multiple small packets with the same key is where AES instructions built-in to a CPU core really shine, vs. a separate accelerator outside the core, or especially off-chip where it can't read from L1d.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks Peter, I agree. Also I changed >1KB, because I think it's typical to en/decrypt at that scale (e.g., web browsers). I'm guessing here.

Answer (score 1):

IBM added hardware accelerators and instructions for 842 compression (a variation on Lempel-Ziv with limited dictionary length) to their Power processors from POWER7+ (2010) onward - https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6665020 , https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/system/files/inline-files/DB2_POWER_NX842_Compression_V1.1.pdf .

In addition, POWER9 (2016) and Power10 added hardware acceleration for the RFC 1951 Deflate algorithm, which is based on LZ77 and is used by zlib and gzip - https://community.ibm.com/community/user/power/blogs/brian-veale1/2022/03/14/gzip-acceleration-with-aix-on-power-systems